# How do I manually sort Chrome's Smart Bar results?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I use Chrome as my default browser. This includes my browser for work.

We have a trac setup that uses folder paths (see example) for the different projects

Example:

- `main.employertracsite.com/projects/projectname`

I want the ability to manually sort the results that are displayed in the auto-complete.

Chrome displays auto-complete based on the usage history of a web address. Which means that a project that isn't my main focus is displayed in the url instead of the one that I've been using more lately.

Example:

- `main.employertracsite.com/projects/alliance` is the project that I'm not using all the time anymore and is showing up in auto-complete
- `main.employertracsite.com/projects/horde` is the project that I am using more often now and want to show up in the auto-complete

I don't want to delete the alliance from my history, but I do want the ability to be able to manually adjust which project shows up in auto-complete. This will be more usable for me in the future because I'm constantly on different projects full-time and they each have their own area.

I also do not want to delete my history.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trickery Method

Bookmark the URL you want rated higher.  Bookmarks in Chrome's Omnibox will be prefixed with a Star Icon and are rated higher than the ones marked with a History icon (the clock).

Brute Force Method - Sqlite3

You can manually edit the history file.  It's a sqlite3 file named "History".

> Linux: `$HOME/.config/google-chrome/Default/`
>
> Windows 7: `c:/Users/<USER>/Application Data/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default`

The 2 main tables you'll want to address are "urls" and "visits".

Please note the History file is locked when Chrome is running, and you'll want to make a backup.  I believe you need you can jack up the visit counter or alternatively delete the lower priority entry and then re-add it manually.

Search Method

Embed the search engine built into the website and use a keyword within the "Managed Search Engine".  Right clicking within most search boxes should list "Add as Search Engine..." in Chrome's context menu.

Comment: Great answer, I went with the bookmark option since it's easier to change based off which project I'm most active on currently.

Comment: For some reason the bookmark option isn't working for me, Chrome is still autocompleting with a non-bookmarked site (www.bing.com) instead of the bookmarked site I want (blender.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Same here - I can confirm this isn't working as of 2022.

Comment: Based on this answer, I used a similar method that seems to work. I went to `google.com` and searched for the url I want to show up first the way I would type it into the URL bar. Example: `facebook.com`. From the google results, I then selected the result that has the exact URL I want to be first priority for the smart bar results. Example: `https://www.facebook.com` Now when I type `fa` or `face`, it automatically suggests `https://www.facebook.com` and not `https://facebook.com/RandomProfileIRecentlyVisited`. I suspect that I could add extra weight by performing the search multiple times.

Comment: @PGmath When a non-bookmarked site shows in the results, hover over the result and then an X should appear to the right of the suggested URL. You can click the X to remove it from the suggestions. On Android, long tap the result and then it should give you an option to remove it or something.